# Is there an R function to aggregate coefficients of interaction effects of a linear model?

Tags: r, linear-regression, tidymodels

I am looking for an automated way to perform linear regression with control for an effect of a variable.
Therefore, I want to:

1. Make a linear model with interaction terms with some factor A.
2. Assign frequencies of a given factor A to the interaction terms.
3. Aggregate coefficients so that the output does not contain the factor. So the final coefficients are  calculated as the weighted average over the factor's frequencies.

Below there is an example of what I want to achieve.

```
#dataset used
mtcars

#base model with drat and wt as predictors
model_simple <- lm(mpg~ drat + wt, data = mtcars)
coefs_simple <- model_simple$coefficients

#model with interaction terms, controlling for the effect of vs
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
model_int <- lm(mpg~ vs*drat + vs*wt, data = mtcars)

coefs_int <- model_int$coefficients
coefs_int

#frequencies of 'vs' levels
vs_tab <- table(mtcars$vs)
vs_tab

#coefficients of the second model
drat_coef <- (vs_tab['0']/sum(vs_tab))*coefs_int['drat'] + (vs_tab['1']/sum(vs_tab))*(coefs_int['drat'] + coefs_int['vs1:drat'])
drat_coef
wt_coef <- (vs_tab['0']/sum(vs_tab))*coefs_int['wt'] + (vs_tab['1']/sum(vs_tab))*(coefs_int['wt'] + coefs_int['vs1:wt'])
wt_coef

coefs_controlled = c(coefs_int['(Intercept)'], 'drat' = as.numeric(drat_coef), wt_coef)

comparison <- data.frame(simple_model_coefs = coefs_simple,
                         coefs_controlled = coefs_controlled)

comparison
```

The dataset and the model in the snippet are meaningless, I am asking for the programming tool to automate the process. If it's not in base R, maybe there is some tidymodels solution?

Answer (score 1):

Below is messy version, prepared quickly, but does the job;)
Works with spaces in factor values and across multiple factors. Assumed that factor column goes with interaction, so pls adjust to your own usage.
Weakness of the solution is basing on columns names, so make sure those are fairly distinctive.

```
#dataset used
mtcars
rm(list= ls())


library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

get_summarised_coeffs  = function(lin_mod) {
  coefs_int <- lin_mod$coefficients
  # # set names
  explanatory_names = rownames(summary(lin_mod)$ coefficients)
  interactions_bool = (lapply(stri_split_fixed(explanatory_names,":"),length) )==2
  factors_data_cols = (lin_mod$model %>% lapply(.,class) %>% unlist)[(lin_mod$model %>% lapply(.,class) %>% unlist) =='factor'] %>% names
  non_factor_data_cols = setdiff(lin_mod$model %>% names() ,factors_data_cols)
  target_colname = ((lin_mod$call %>% as.character )[2] %>% stri_split_fixed( ., "~"))[[1]][1] %>% stri_trim_both()
  non_factor_expl_cols = setdiff(non_factor_data_cols , target_colname)
  # get weights of factors
  weights_interaction_columns = factors_data_cols %>% lapply(.,function(x) {
    return(table(lin_mod$model[[x]]) / length(lin_mod$model[[x]]))
  } )
  names(weights_interaction_columns) = factors_data_cols
  
  # iterate over weights
  weighted_intercepts = weights_interaction_columns %>% seq_along() %>% lapply(., function(iter) {
    # set weights
    factor_weights = weights_interaction_columns[[iter]]
    factor_name = names(weights_interaction_columns)[iter]
    names(factor_weights) = paste0(factor_name,names(factor_weights))
    
    
    # iterate over non factor columns to adjust with according weight
    non_factor_expl_cols %>% lapply(.,function(x) {
      interaction_name = (names(coefs_int)[grepl (x,names(coefs_int)) & grepl (factor_name,names(coefs_int))]) 
      factor_value_name = interaction_name %>% stri_split_fixed(.,":") %>% unlist
      factor_value_name=factor_value_name[grepl(factor_name,factor_value_name)]
      if (length(factor_value_name) > 0 )
        data.frame('colname' =x,  'factor' = factor_name , 'weighted_coeff' = factor_weights[factor_value_name] * coefs_int[interaction_name])
    }) 
  } ) %>% do.call(bind_rows,.)
  
  
  
  # sum up coeffs of according column 
  result = non_factor_expl_cols %>% lapply(.,function(colname_effect) { 
    coefs_int[colname_effect] + weighted_intercepts[weighted_intercepts$colname  == colname_effect,]$weighted_coeff %>% sum
  }) %>% unlist
  
  
  if (!is.na( coefs_int['(Intercept)']))  result = c(   coefs_int['(Intercept)'],result )
  return(result)
}



#base model with drat and wt as predictors
model_simple <- lm(mpg~ drat + wt, data = mtcars)

#model with interaction terms, controlling for the effect of vs
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
model_int <- lm(mpg~ vs*drat + vs*wt, data = mtcars)
get_summarised_coeffs(model_int)


#check with multiple factors
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
model_int <- lm(mpg~ vs*drat + wt*am, data = mtcars)
get_summarised_coeffs(model_int)
```

Comment: Widzisz Adam, nawet stacka specjalnie założyłem ;P

Comment: gościu, myślałem, że jakiś one-liner może jest :D ale dziękuję bardzo